# how to handle invalid date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, exception

There is a column that displays some statements for transactions

Ex: **'date-05-03-2020-Tran-100002345-W.44321-CR-9999eu843'**

And I fetched out only the date from the statement. In some cases, there is an invalid date such as  date-05-**032**-2020 (three numbers in month instead of two numbers)

So when I executed the query I got an error as I am using TO_DATE function to convert the varchar to date after extracting it from the previous statement

So what I need is a function like IfError in excel sheet but in oracle SQL

Ex: if the DATE_x is invalid then replace it with DATE_x2

```
with x as(
select TO_DATE('01/20/2021','DD-MM-YYYY') DATE_x,
TO_DATE('01/02/2021','DD-MM-YYYY') DATE_x2
from dual
)

select 
DATE_x2
from x;
```

Please advise

Comment: If PL/SQL is an option, you can write a function with an exception handler to handle invalid dates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `default... on conversion error`  parameter in to_date: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118

So you can write `TO_DATE('01/20/2021' default '01-01-2020' on conversion error, 'DD-MM-YYYY')` or `TO_DATE('01/20/2021' default null on conversion error ,'DD-MM-YYYY')`.

There is also `validate_conversion` function: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD

Answer (score 2):

One option is to check date format with `regexp_like`. Example you posted suggests it is `'dd-mm-yyyy'` which means [2 digits - 2 digits - 4 digits]. Certainly, `[43-85-0123]` "matches" such a format but doesn't represent a valid date. Anyway, see if it helps. In my example, I'm substituting an invalid date value with today's date. Read comments within code.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    -- sample data; the 2nd row is invalid
  3    (select 'date-05-03-2020-Tran-100002345-W.44321-CR-9999eu843'  from dual union all
  4     select 'date-05-032-2020-Tran-100002345-W.44321-CR-9999eu843' from dual
  5    ),
  6  exdate as
  7    -- extract "date" substrings (values between 1st and 4th "-" character)
  8    (select col,
  9            substr(col, instr(col, '-') + 1,
 10                        instr(col, '-', 1, 4) - instr(col, '-') - 1
 11                  ) datum
 12     from test
 13    )
 14  select col,
 15         case when regexp_like(datum, '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}') then
 16                   to_date(datum, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
 17              else trunc(sysdate)
 18         end as result
 19  from exdate
 20  /

COL                                                  RESULT
---------------------------------------------------- ----------
date-05-03-2020-Tran-100002345-W.44321-CR-9999eu843  05-03-2020
date-05-032-2020-Tran-100002345-W.44321-CR-9999eu843 01-08-2021

SQL>
```

Comment: Dear @littlefoot many thanks, this is a great solution. but I wanted to replace the invalid values with other values. because I have some garbage data in this table as some rare cases there is no dash '-' after 'date' word, or there is null date and so on

Comment: You're welcome. Saying that you want to replace invalid values with **other** values - *which* other values? I replaced it with SYSDATE (that's also "other" value, is it not?). As of other kinds of "garbage" ... well, that makes things complicated as you'll have to parse each string itself, find out which "garbage category" it represents and then *do something*. More complex it gets, more code it requires, so - maybe you should consider using PL/SQL instead of SQL.

Comment: what I meant with other values, is another column that has creation date, the date of insertion of this record.

Comment: Aha; in that case, it would just be `case when ... ELSE another_column END as result`.